# Splitting text into 2d array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, split

I am trying to split a block of text into a 2d array.  I know how to split a line into an array of words, and I know how to split multiple lines into an array of lines, but I would like to do both simultaneously.

For example, I want this :

> Tim is nice
>   Jim is mean

would become

> ((Tim,is,nice),(Jim,is,mean))

So Far, I have been able to use

```
Str1.Split(new String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

To make the example string into:

> (Tim is nice,Jim is mean)

And I've used `Str1.Split` to convert `"Tim is nice"` into

> (Tim,is,nice)

Also, if any of my code is bad syntax or anything like that let me know, I'm a Python programmer primarily.

Comment: How is the first block stored/where is it?  Does it have newline chars in long text?

Comment: @Plutonix It's stored in a string variable with newline chars. I am able to separate the rows with this : Str1.Split(new String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)

Comment: Add that to the question ([Edit]) so we know what the starting point is.

Comment: @Plutonix I did that, thank you for your quick responses btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isnt a 2D array:

> ((Tim,is,nice),(Jim,is,mean))

That is a jagged array or an array of arrays.  Since each line/sentence may not have the same number of words, it is a better choice.  For your example, you will have an array of 2 to hold each "line", then each of those will hold an array of however many words there are.

```
Dim original = "Tim is nice" & Environment.NewLine & "Jim is very mean"

Dim lines = original.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine.ToString},
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim results(lines.Count - 1)() As String
For n As Int32 = 0 To lines.Count - 1
    ' store array of words to results(n)
    results(n) = lines(n).Split(" "c)
Next
' glue a line back together and show it
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", results(1)))
```

`results(0)` will hold the Tim words, `results(1)` will hold the Jim words. Results (of the writeline):

> Jim is very mean

Comment: So would results(0,2) be "nice"? Also what is the difference between the Count and Length functions?

Comment: `results(0,2) ` would work if it was a 2D array, `results(0)(2) ` would be `"nice"`.  There is no real difference between Length and Count. Count is an extension method which syntactically allows array refs to match other modern collections.

Comment: Ok, thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. As a side note, the data I'm working with will always have the same amount of words on each line. Would there be any advatanges to using a 2d array instead of the jagged one?

Comment: In all honesty, I would only use an array for static items: `Private Stooges As String() = {"Larry", "Moe", "Curly"}` most everything else, I would use a `List(Of T)` here, maybe a `List(Of String())`: the word count might be the same, but allows an unknown/arbitrary number of lines.

Comment: Yea, I'm still just beginning to learn VB. I know I always have at least 1 row of data, at most 40, and they will all have the same amount of words. I used the word array because that is what Split creates generically, no clue which one is better for my situation